# No "Keep in Launcher" command in launcher menu for some applications

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, unity, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add applications to the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37434/how-do-i-add-applications-to-the-unity-launcher)

Hi, I have some applications installed which don't have a "Keep in Launcher" option in launcher right-click menu. These apps (emacs for example) were installed via Ubuntu Software Manager.

Windows 7 can do it, you know.

[image]

Comment: oh, maybe it is, sorry. no answer there though

Answer (score 1):

Example, for Emacs,

- right-click on the top applet
- click on 'Add to Panel'
- select Application Launcher ..

Comment: sorry, which one is top? with the ubuntu logo? I click and nothing happens