# How do I add applications to the Unity launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher

How do I add apps to the Launcher?

Answer (score 22):

There are a few ways to add applications. The easiest is to run the application, then right click on it and select Keep In Launcher:

[image]

The second way is to search for an application and then drag the result into the launcher:

or you could just browse the applications lens and drag any of those onto the launcher:

[image]

[Here is a video demonstrating that](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRFaEXmrnYE&html5=1) .

... and lastly, the Ubuntu Software Center has a feature that lets you put the icon on the launcher right as you install it:

[image]

Or you can also make launchers [manually by making .desktop files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity).