# Add custom icons to the launcher in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: 11.04, unity, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add applications to the launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37434/how-do-i-add-applications-to-the-launcher)

i have installed 11.04 i want to know whether i can add custom icons on launcher or not

Comment: i'm sure you can