# Mikogo icon lancher?

Tags: unity, shortcuts, appmenu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add applications to the launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37434/how-do-i-add-applications-to-the-launcher)

I have convinced a few family members to switch to Ubuntu/Kubuntu, however they are half a country away (live in Canada) and I need to be able to guide them through things at some times.
So I had them install Mikogo so we can share desktops and I can have remote access, all easily using just meeting ID's after starting the application.
The only thing is that to launch it you have to go into the downloaded Mikogo file and double click there. Anyone know how I can get that to appear in Unity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is what you need however if you want the application to appear in the screen that loads when you click on the top left corner the procedure is quite different. Let me know if thats what you need and I will run you through it.

In order to keep programs in the Unity sidebar all you have to do is open the program and dock the app.To do this you will need to open the program. Once this is done you should see the program icon on the left of your screen with a little white arrow on it. Right click on this icon and click on "Keep in Launcher"

This will now hold the program shortcut in the bar.

I hope this helps

Chris

Comment: Duh! Brain fart on my part. thank you. things are much more simple then you think sometimes. yay for unity.

Comment: Not a problem, and one more Yay for Unity!