# How to stick an icon on the menu bar?

Tags: taskbar

I'm really tired; I can't think of words right now, which is why I said "stick it" on the "menu bar" despite that I know there's more accurate wording. But hopefully you know what I mean.

I downloaded TextAdept, a simple text editor program, and I want to stick in on the bar, but when I drag the icon over it just bounces back.

I'm new to Ubuntu, what do I do?

Comment: ok - please clarify which very of ubuntu you are using as well as the desktop environment - e.g. 11.10?  Unity/Gnome-Shell?  If you are talking about Unity - are you referring to the panel at the top of the screen or the launcher down the left-hand side of the screen?

Comment: Launcher along the left side. Gnome.

Comment: @Aerovistae - please let us know (edit your question) with what you have tried from this Q&A.  Thanks.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/37434/how-do-i-add-applications-to-the-unity-launcher

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/78968/46531) could help you in that case, as well as some other answers to this question.