# Problem with Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04

I clicked delete on the Foxfire icon. How can I restore it? Problems were occurring after an update downloaded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add applications to the Unity launcher?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/37434/how-do-i-add-applications-to-the-unity-launcher)

Answer (score 2):

I would assume that if you open the Dash, and type `firefox` that in fact *FireFox* will still run.  While it is open and running, you should be able to right click on the icon in the Dash bar for Firefox, and then choose to "Add to favorites"

Please note that Ubuntu 15.04 is past end-of-life, and you will have increasing trouble getting support for that version of the operating system.